# Resolving the location/registration of an executable in the system?

Tags: path, executable, system-information

I am on Ubuntu 11.04, Gnome 2. I had at a certain point installed Adobe Reader (`acroread`), however "off-tree" (at a non-standard location) - and I just noticed something weird about this executable.

First, `which` reports:

```
$ which acroread
/media/mydisk/AdobeReader/Adobe/Reader9/bin/acroread
```

Ok, so it is on a different partition than the system root `/`; in this case, I'd expect a symlink to this `acroread` to be present somewhere in the `$PATH`, e.g. in `/usr/bin`. So let's try `locate`:

```
$ locate acroread
~/.icons/All-blacks/scalable/apps/acroread.png
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/orca/scripts/apps/acroread
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/orca/scripts/apps/acroread/__init__.py
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/orca/scripts/apps/acroread/__init__.pyc
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/orca/scripts/apps/acroread/script.py
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/orca/scripts/apps/acroread/script.pyc
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/acroread.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/icons/acroread.png
/usr/share/pyshared/orca/scripts/apps/acroread
/usr/share/pyshared/orca/scripts/apps/acroread/__init__.py
/usr/share/pyshared/orca/scripts/apps/acroread/script.py
/usr/share/scribus-trunk/icons/acroread16.png
/usr/share/scribus-trunk/icons/acroread22.png
/usr/share/scribus-trunk/icons/acroread32.png
```

Weird - nothing here seems related, except for `acroread.desktop`. I recall in Gnome, one can "register" an application by placing a `.desktop` file in a respective system directory; but if I check `acroread.desktop`:

```
$ cat /usr/share/app-install/desktop/acroread.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
X-AppInstall-Package=acroread
X-AppInstall-Proprietary=true
X-AppInstall-Channel=natty-partner
X-AppInstall-LicenseUri=/usr/share/app-install/channels/natty-partner.eula
X-AppInstall-Architectures=i386,amd64
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Adobe Reader 9
Icon=acroread.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Office;Viewer;
StartupNotify=true
```

... there's nothing in there about `/media/mydisk` location ?! Actually, this `.desktop` file looks like a pre-prepared icon, which would start the installer if you click it?!

So how come `which` finds this executable -- on a partition other than the system one? Maybe it's my `.bashrc`?:

```
$ grep 'acro\|Adobe' ~/.bashrc
$
```

Nope, nothing there.

So - how does the system know, that when I type `acroread` in the terminal, it should run `/media/mydisk/.../acroread` - and yet there is no symlink in system path, no mention in `~/.bashrc`, and not even any relevant Gnome `.desktop` files in the root filesystem, either?

EDIT: The shell I use is `bash` , and `type` reports:

```
$ type acroread 
acroread is hashed (/media/mydisk/AdobeReader/Adobe/Reader9/bin/acroread)
```

I've also tried this:

```
$ while read line; do if [ -f "${line}" ]; then grep -rH 'acroread' "${line}"; fi; done < <(locate applications)
/usr/share/application-registry/gnome-vfs.applications:acroread
/usr/share/application-registry/gnome-vfs.applications: command=acroread
```

but the `gnome-vfs.applications` doesn't contain much about the location:

```
$ grep -A7 acroread /usr/share/application-registry/gnome-vfs.applications 
acroread
    command=acroread
    name=Adobe Acrobat Reader
    can_open_multiple_files=true
    expects_uris=false
    requires_terminal=false
    mime_types=application/pdf

applix
```

EDIT2: as @MichaelHomer noted, the reason the shell can call this executable is that the directory was in the `$PATH`:

```
$ for path in ${PATH//:/ }; do echo "$path" | grep 'Adobe\|acro'; done
/media/mydisk/AdobeReader/Adobe/Reader9/bin
```

However, the weird thing now is - how did this directory end up in `$PATH`? As mentioned earlier, certainly not by being added to my `.bashrc` - or for that matter, in any `bashrc`:

```
$ while read fnline; do if [ -f "${fnline}" ]; then echo "...(${fnline})..."; grep -rH 'acro\|Adobe' "${fnline}"; fi; done < <(locate bashrc)
...(/etc/bash.bashrc)...
...(/etc/skel/.bashrc)...
...(~/.bashrc)...
...(~/.bashrc-orig)...
...(~/.bashrc_mine)...
...(/home/aaa/.bashrc)...
...(/home/bbb/.bashrc)...
...(/usr/share/base-files/dot.bashrc)...
...(/usr/share/doc/adduser/examples/adduser.local.conf.examples/bash.bashrc)...
...(/usr/share/doc/adduser/examples/adduser.local.conf.examples/skel/dot.bashrc)...
```

... so the question now is: how did this directory end up in path?

Comment: What is `$PATH`? What does `type acroread` give you? What is your shell?

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04 reached end of life years ago and has not been getting security fixes.  You need to stop using it at once, as continuing to use an unsupported OS will get you hacked sooner or later.

Comment: You can get acroread from `deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org wheezy main non-free`.

Comment: Many thanks, @MichaelHomer - see post update; it turns out my `$PATH` starts with `/media/mydisk/AdobeReader/Adobe/Reader9/bin:/opt/OpenPrinting-lm1100/bin:...` so that is the solution; feel free to post an answer, I'll accept it! Thanks @psusi - I'm well aware of that, unfortunately I'm working on a project using this older version; otherwise I would have updated a long time ago. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @FaheemMitha - I already do have `acroread`, I was just wondering how does the shell know where it is located; and it turns out now it was in the `$PATH`; cheers!

Comment: @sdaau binary packages which use standard location and are known to the package management system are better.

Comment: @MichaelHomer and everyone - just realized that I in fact don't know how did that directory end up in `$PATH` to begin with (see edit); so now I need to know how I could inspect that. @FaheemMitha - agreed, but in this case I'd want to [test differences between two different versions of `acroread`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67663/did-anyone-succeed-in-playing-embedded-movies-inside-acrobat-in-linux). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was hoping I could reach an answer to this, without grepping through the entire filesystem; but apparently that was impossible - especially since this adding to the `PATH` it's apparently my doing `:)`

So, first I grepped through the entire root filesystem, making sure not to cross filesystem boundaries (`-xdev`), and grepping in binary mode (`-ao`) for either `acroread` or `Adobe` as characteristic word in the full path to the executable - saving the results in a different filesystem:

```
find / -xdev -type f -print0 2>/dev/null \
  | xargs -0 grep -Hao 'acroread\|Adobe....' 2>/dev/null \
  | tee /media/mydisk/found.txt
```

Once I had the found results, I inspected them visually, and found that this command for grepping through the `found.txt` results file would eventually give the answer:

```
while read tline; do \
  IFS=":"; declare -a arrIN=($tline); \
  grep -H Adobe/ "${arrIN[0]}" \
  | grep '\$PATH'; \
done < \
  <(grep Adobe/ /media/mydisk/found.txt | sort | uniq)
```

... and the answer is:

```
~/.profile:PATH="/media/mydisk/AdobeReader/Adobe/Reader9/bin:$PATH"
```

So, apparently there is also a `~/.profile` file, where additions to the `PATH` are also registered/executed - and apparently I had appended (well, prepended) the Adobe Reader directory to the `PATH` environment variable there.

Well, mystery solved - thanks to all for their comments!